# Image folder creation in web api using concatenate strings

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-web-api

I am new to c# ,Here I'm trying to form a URL to store the image in API itself .

I want to create a folder in the following structure

**Images_Folder --> Fruits_Folder--> Seedless_Folder --> Image.jpg**

coding :

```
string imageURL = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/");

folderPath = imageURL + formData.RootFolder + formData.TypeFolder + "/";

filePath = (folderPath + postedFile.FileName);

postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
```

By using the above code it stores the image in the following structure.

**Images-->Fruits_FolderSeedless_Folder --> Image.jpg**

While debugging the code I could see the URL format as follows

**"D:\Projects\Dot Net\FruitsDisplay\FruitsDisplaySolution\Images\FruitsSeedless/"**

Ex: Images-->FruitsSeedless-->Image.jpg

But I want it should be as **Images-->Fruits-->Seedless-->Image.jpg**

can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: Use `Path.Combine` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let OS decide what to use for sub directories, as it might not always be the familiar `\` character. Using `Path.Combine()` method uses the character that is valid in that environment:

```
folderPath =Path.Combine(imageURL,formData.RootFolder, formData.TypeFolder, postedFile.FileName);
```